# Need some clarity on CAS basic configuration

Tags: php, authentication, single-sign-on, cas, accounts

I am trying to use CAS as my Single Sign On service and I am really having a hard time understanding the basics. This is how I issue my requests:

start page: index.php:

```
<?php

include_once('../accounts/cas/config.php');
include_once('../accounts/cas/CAS.php');
phpCAS::setDebug();
phpCAS::client(CAS_VERSION_2_0, 'www.domain.com', 443, '/accounts');
phpCAS::setNoCasServerValidation();
phpCAS::forceAuthentication();

if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
    phpCAS::logout();
}

if (phpCAS::isAuthenticated()) {
    $name = phpCAS::getUser();
}

?>
```

When I point my browser to this page, it redirects to this URL: `https://www.domain.com/accounts/login?service=https://www.domain.com`

I created a file `accounts/login/index.php` for this request and I don't know what code must be in there. Do I have to write an html form to log the user in? Or does CAS do this for me?

My problem is that I am really missing the basics and I could not find any documentation I could understad. My file structure is like this:

```
/my_app (accessible via: https://www.domain.com)
    /index.php
/accounts
    /cas
        /config.php
        /CAS.php
    /login
        /index.php
    /certificate
        /domain.crt
```

Any light on this will highly appreciated (even a tutorial / example I can follow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a CAS Server running at www.domain.com/accounts it will provide the login form.

http://www.jasig.org/cas/download

Comment: Thanks. I didn't even know there was a difference between CAS server and phpCAS library. Last question: is CAS only available in JSP (JAVA)? Isn't there a PHP alternative to it? Please help out if you know any. I've never used this before.

Comment: I think the CAS server is Java only